# In probability, when to count collections vs sequences?

Tags: probability

I recently started taking a class on basic probability and I'm having trouble truly understanding when I should count collections to solve probability problems and when I should instead count sequences.

For example, we've gone over how the probability of being dealt a full house in a 5-card poker hand can be represented via collections:

> Choose 1 of 13 denominations for the first 3 cards, then choose 3 of 4 suits for them, then choose 1 of 12 remaining denominations for the last 2 cards, then choose 2 of 5 suits for them.  Those are the favorable outcomes, divide them by all possible outcomes and get:

> $\frac{{13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 3}{12 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}}{52 \choose 5}$

And we've also gone over The Birthday Paradox and how the probability that at least 2 out of 23 people share a birthday (assuming 365 possible days) can be represented via sequences:

> We find the number of sequences of distinct birthdays, so 365 possibilities for the first person, 364 for the second, and so on down to 343.  Divide that by the total number of possible birthday sequences to get the probability that everyone has distinct birthdays; subtract that from 1 to get the probability of at least 2 birthdays overlapping:

> $1-\frac{\frac{365!}{(365-22)!}}{365^{23}}$

At first glance, I wanted to solve *both* of these problems by counting collections.  And while I now know that wasn't correct, my brain doesn't really understand why.  I've been in the woods for days on this, looking over a variety of threads (and undoubtedly searching with the incorrect keywords) as well as trying to formulate my own hypotheses that never quite seem sensible.
**Can someone help me to better understand what to look for in *any* probability problem to know whether I should be counting collections or sequences?**

*Additional context: from what I've seen while searching on my own, I see a wide variety of different terms and syntaxes that seem to be used to address problems like these, but that seem entirely outside my understanding.  So to clarify what things I'm familiar with, so far we've covered counting items with the Multiplication and Subtraction Principles, counting items in sequences and collections that either allow or don't allow repetition of items, Binominal/Multinomial Coefficients, and probability being the number of favorable outcomes divided by the total possible outcomes.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it's helpful to understand that both problems could be interpreted and solved using "sequences".

That is, for the first problem, if you really wanted to, you could count all $5$-card sequences that are full houses as follows: First choose which $3$ card slots in your hand are part of the "three of the kind", then for the three of a kind, choose the denomination, then first suit, then second suit, then third suit, then choose the denomination for the pair, then choose the first suit for that pair, and finally choose a second suit.  Divide that by the total number of $5$ card sequences.

In this case, your calculation becomes

$$\frac{\binom{5}{3} \cdot 13\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2 \cdot 12 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{52 \cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48},$$

which after some manipulation coincides with your original formula.

I am not advising that you take the above approach, but the point rather is that you can imagine each problem starts out as a question about sequences, and then re-interpreting it as a problem about collections is a special convenience that is allowed only when

1. We are counting sequences in which order does not matter (ie, a sequence is a success if and only if every permutation of it is also a success)

and

2. Crucially, ***objects are selected without replacement.***

In the birthday problem, order doesn't really matter, but objects (in this case birthdays) are selected with replacement, i.e., once one person is born on a given day, another person can still be born on the same day with presumably equal probability.  This is what prevents you from solving the problem purely through collections, and so you need to use the "default" interpretation using sequences.